# Calculating $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i(x|y)}e^{-a(|y_1|+ \cdots + |y_n|)}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I need to calculate $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i(x|y)}e^{-a(|y_1|+ \cdots + |y_n|)}dy$$
$a>0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(x|y)$ denotes the usual scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I have think that I can use the Fubini's theorem to see it as product of $n$ integrals, all over $\mathbb{R}$, the problem is that for the case $n=1$ I couldn't find the value of that integral. Any hint?

Comment: In $1$D you have $$\int_R e^{-a|y|}e^{-ixy}dy$$ This is a known Fourier transform which evaluates to something like $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$, but this integral is not too hard to do on your own. Just split it into two integrals.

Comment: Do you mean in something like $( \int_\mathbb{R}e^{-a|y|}cos(xy)dy -i\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-a|y|}sin(xy)dy )$ 
@NinadMunshi

Comment: No, split the domain so there is no absolute value.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that and I tell you what I get @NinadMunshi

Comment: You can define the vector $x$ in $R^N$ as $(x_1,x_2,.....x_n)$, so your get the product of terms designated by @Ninad Munshi :  $\int_R e^{-a|y|}e^{-ix_ky}dy$, $k=1,2,...n$

Comment: I guess $x\in \mathbb{R}$ because $(x|y)$ denote the usual scalar product and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ @Svyatoslav

Comment: @Ricardo Calderon I made a typo. I just wanted to say that if$(x|y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...+x_ny_n$, we have a product of integrals $\int_R e^{-a|y_k|}e^{-ix_ky_k}dy$

Comment: Yes, I see. 
It is correct that I argue that by Fubini's theorem $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i(x|y)}e^{-a(|y_1|+ \cdots + |y_n|}dy = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i x_k y_k }e^{-a|y_k|} dy_k$? or, strictly speaking, should I try something else? @NinadMunshi